# How do I display the distro information after the MOTD at ssh login?

Tags: linux

I am trying to display the distro information right after the MOTD when a user logs in.

I have to place a script in `/etc/profile.d` that has `hostnamectl` in it but the information does not display unless you `su` to a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I added a script called sysinfo.sh to /etc/profile.d/ and had the single command `hostnamectl` in it. I get what I was looking for when people log in.